# deallocating a variable in kotlin

Tags: junit, kotlin

In kotlin, for writing tests, I have a guice injector created before each tests in the setUp phase and then I try to deallocate it in the tearDown phase:

```
class MyTestClass {
    ....
    var injector: Injector? = null
    ...
    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        ...
        injector = Guice.createInjector(modules)
        ...
    }
    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        ...
        injector = null
    }

    @Test
    fun myFirstTest() {
        myInstance = injector?.getInstance(Key.get(MyClass::class.java))
        // use myInstance here
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

My question is that in Kotlin land, is such deallocation necessary at all? And if it is necessary, what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not necessary, and isn't even deallocation. All you're doing is rebinding `injector` to null. The old value is still hanging out in memory without a reference. Memory is cleaned up by the garbage collector when it deems appropriate.

Comment: Hmm, is there a way to structure the code such that I can be certain that the injector is cleaned from memory then?

Comment: Not really. That's a design decision of the JVM. It manages memory for you, and is generally quite good at it. Trying to subvert it usually leads to serious performance and memory issues. So long as you make sure to close connections to resources when you're done with them, you shouldn't need it to be cleaned from memory. (The JVM will clean it's memory when it exits too, so don't think it will stick around after your tests are done.)